# How to get base url in managed package?

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package, url

I have a requirement where I need to get Base URL in managed package class.
I am using `Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()` to get base URL
but getting

> https://custom-domain-name--prefix.ap2.visual.force.com
>   instead of 
>   https://custom-domain-name.my.salesforce.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use relative URL, instead of absolute one?

Comment: For Relative URL there will be a lot of combinations for different org, for example- custom domain

Comment: If the answer in the question I've linked does not answer your question, please [edit] your question to explain how it differs from the other question.

Comment: @sfdcfox , I just found the solution, I have created custom setting and inserted a record in that custom setting using post install script. During post install script we get base URL which does not include prefix of the package .